# Carry over and show custom Java annotation when Overriding

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotations, overriding

I am looking for a way to be able to carry over and display custom Java annotation when Overriding methods that are decorated with said Annotations.

Consider having this custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface SeeMe {

}
```

And consider decorating a method with it:

```
@SeeMe
public void iSeeYou() {
    // Do something
}
```

How can i have this @SeeMe annotation be carried over and shown when i Override the above method?

```
@Override
@SeeMe
public void iSeeYou() {
    super.iSeeYou();
}
```

Basically i want the same effect the @Nullable and @NonNull annotations achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the annotation processor has defined the semantics of the annotation, including whether the annotation is inherited.

- The author might write the annotation processor to inherit annotations, so that the user has to write fewer annotations.
- The author might write the annotation processor to not inherit annotations, so that the meaning of a class is obvious by looking at the class alone, without having to read every superclass as well.

Either of these is a defensible choice.  I tend to lean toward the latter, because it improves readability, and code is read more often than it is written.

If you wish to change the behavior, you will need to modify the semantics of the annotation processor that processes `@SeeMe` by modifying its source code.  (Or write an annotation processor if there isn't one already.  If there isn't one, the annotation will not be inherited.)

Comment: Ive been looking into annotation processing for a few days now, thank you for pointing me in that direction. Can you please be more specific as to what i should be looking for? I can find resources about code generation but nothing that would help me achieve what i asked for.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on annotation processing on the web.  An example of an annotation processor that guarantees code correctness, rather than creating new code, is the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/).  I don't know whether this is the sort of thing you are looking for, because you have not yet said what your goal is, and you haven't said what you have found so far.